# How to store checkbox options to use in other classes?

Tags: java, javafx

Im using a method in my FXMLController to check if radio buttons are selected and storing them in a bollean array. I then will be calling this method in another class to get the boolean values to see which are selected to perform perfrom different actions using if statements accordingly.

```
public boolean[] GetSelectedOption() {


      boolean[] OptionsValue = new boolean[2];

    OptionsValue[0] = StripHtmlOption.isSelected();
    OptionsValue[1] = StripHtmlOption.isSelected();


        return OptionsValue;

}
```

Is this the right way of storing checkbox/radiobutton options? Is there a better way of doing this? As I can imagine this isn't very object orientated?  Im a java beginner.

Here is the code where im trying to call the options/boolean values in another class. This code doesnt work though.

```
   public String StripHtml(String html, String DomainName) {

    FXMLController FetchOptions = new FXMLController();

    boolean[] OptionsValue = FetchOptions.GetSelectedOption();

    OptionsValue[0] = StripHtmlvalue;
    OptionsValue[1] =  = StripLinkValue;

    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(StripHtmlvalue)) {

        System.out.println("Some code will go here");

    } else {

    }


    return Stringyettobemade;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you want to use the selected optiones?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Added the code where I wish to grab the values and do if statements from

Comment: `FXMLController FetchOptions = new FXMLController();
 boolean[] OptionsValue = FetchOptions.GetSelectedOption();` Even if you do load the fxml in the `FXMLController` constructor - When do you expect the user input to happen?

Comment: I hope this method is ran when the user clicks a button. So before the user clicks the button he./she will be able select which options they would like. Thanks to Niton my code is right StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 because its not fetching the proper values.

Answer (score 0):

```
OptionsValue[0] = StripHtmlvalue;
OptionsValue[1] =  = StripLinkValue;
```

At first please use lower case variable names.
At seccond why do you overwrite the values?
I think what you want is to GET the values so the right code will be:

```
StripHtmlvalue = optionValue[0];
```

and what should this do : `= =`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
boolean[] optionsValue ={stripHtmlvalue.isSelected(),stripLinkValue.isSelected()};
```